# Setting ViewController size

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a viewcontroller from which I call a second small viewcontroller with a certain size. Then from the second one, if the user wants, he can call the camera, full screen, but the problem is that when it is dismissed, the 2 viewcontroller changes size. why? how can I prevent it?

Comment: How are you calling the second small controller, and how is its view added to the view hierarchy?

Comment: And how do you adjust the size of a view controller other than by adding or removing lines of code?

Comment: (But try turning off (in Interface Builder) "Autoresize Subviews" on your main view.)